# Проверка расширения файла при загрузке на сервер

Tags: php, html

Хочу сделать проверку, чтобы на сайт можно было закачать только изображения.

```
  $filename = $_FILES["img1"]["tmp_name"]; // В переменную $filename заносим точное имя файла (включая расширение).
  $allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.png'); 
 echo $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

 if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
 die('Данный тип файла фотографий не поддерживается. Вернитесь назад и выберите фотографию с друугим разрешением .jpeg, .gif или .png ');
```

echo $ext выдает .tmp Как разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: используйте

$ext=[pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pathinfo.php)($filename)['extension'];

чтобы корректно расширения получать, `print_r($allowed_types);` в студию

Comment: У меня в $filename тоже временный файл лежит.

Comment: а, не заметил, а зачем у вас там имя временного файла ? 

$ext=pathinfo($_FILES["img1"]['name'])['extension'];

Comment: в переменную получается нельзя класть $_FILES["img1"]['name'] ?

Comment: можно, только у вас там tmp_name

Comment: а, все ок. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы проверить валидность файла нужно не расширение смотреть, а тип. Иначе вам под "правильным" расширением подсунут что угодно, с какими угодно последствиями. Для картинок можете воспользоваться функцией [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), заодно и устранится возможное несоответствие типа (например, если жпег зальют с расширением png), и пригодится для дальнейшей обработки картинки, если такая планируется, и проверки ширины/высоты на допустимость.